# Display multiple points with exact same value in scatter HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

i got a pool of data with exact same value in a scatter plot with HighCharts as in : 
http://jsfiddle.net/DvbHa/1/

i want to be able to display them in tooltip when i go over it to be able to click them individualy

is something like that possible?
Thx all

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
       tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x}, {point.y}'
                },
        series: [{
            data: [[10, 5],
                   [15, 6],
                   [10, 5],
                   [15, 7],
                   [13, 6],
                   [13, 6]]
        }],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that is implemented in most major data visualization software packages is jittering - a function that adds small amounts of random noise to the data points so that each data point is slightly offset from it's actual data values.

This is a trade off with precision, of course, but those are the kinds of choices that are to be made when displaying data.

There is not a jittering option in Highcharts, but with a little digging you should be able to find or create a solution.

I have had some moderate success doing this on the server side before sending the data to the chart.

First check for any duplicates.  If there aren't any, go no further.

If there are, create an array of any duplicate points for any point that has duplicates.
Loop through each array and add random decimal values to the x and y values of each point.

Comment: it's a good trick but i would prefer custom tooltip on mouse over thank's for answer

Answer (score 0):

To add click events, use [plotOptions.scatter.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.events).

However, I don't know what is the purpose of displaying the same points in the same place with the same value.

Comment: Pawel - the point is simply that when creating a scatter plot, you very often have data that occupies the same space.  The problem as stated is not how to add a click event, but how to have the tooltip tell you that there are multiple points at that coordinate. There may be multiple series represented, and there may be custom tooltip information to display for each point.

Comment: If coordinates are the same, points are the same, so tooltip should display the same value. Maybe solution is to create objects, and instead of using duplicated points, use custom property and display it in a tooltip? And for multiple series, use shared tooltip.

Comment: I think part of the problem is simply knowing if there are multiple points in the first place.  I use transparency to help with that personally.  The other issue is custom tooltip information that will differ between points, and then if you have a chart where you click a point to open a page or a popup to see additional data - you can only click the top point if there are multiple.

Comment: Yes, that's true - Highcharts doesn't have built-in option for that. Users always can use uservoice :)

Answer (score 0):

Increase size of the plot by using marker radius and you can differentiate the plots at same location.

```
marker: {
    radius: 13
  }
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.marker.radius

See this one helps or not

Answer (score 0):

Since 7.0.2, HighCharts now does officially support jittering for scatter plots.

See here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.jitter